# How to send fake call broadcast on android

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call, telephonymanager

I am trying to send a broadcast to simulate an incoming call.
I added the permission in AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

When I try to run the program, the phone reboots.(Emulator too).

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    intent.putExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING);
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER", "923982398");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong as I can't find anything in the docs but I'd say it's not possible to 'spoof' a call ringing broadcast. It's almost certainly reserved as 'system only'.

Think about it - if apps could do this, it may simply result in 'mischief' rather than anything malicious but it isn't something that I'd like to happen on my phone.

Create your own 'phone ringing' action to use for testing purposes and have your BroadcastReceiver listen for it. When you come to release the app then simply change the BroadcastReceiver's intent filter to listen for the real one.

Comment: I thought the same, but there are few apps in the market. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.agilestorm.fakecall.free&feature=search_result      and https://market.android.com/search?q=fake+caller&so=1&c=apps

Comment: @dcanh121: I'm pretty certain that everything about those apps is fake. In other words, they're not actually using the actual phone to fake the call - they simply play a ring-tone and show a 'screen' that makes it look like there's an incoming call.

Comment: You are absolutely right, they are fake. Thanks. But I'm just wondering if they are able to find if Moto blur is installed or the HTC sense and show the appropriate UI.

Comment: @dcanh121: It's possible to find information about manufacturer, model etc using android.os.Build which might be enough to do that. See here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 0):

I Downloaded some of the fake Caller Apps from play store and tested them. 
I found that the App Raises an Event which displays the pre-mentioned GUI on the Top of Lock Screen and adds the entry into call logs using the insert method of ContentResolver.

The app does not use the inbuild Calling (Broadcast) mechanism. it just fakes the GUI on the Screen and plays the Default Ringtone/Vibration.

As per my Knowledge, I think it is not possible to fake a call ringing broadcast